# Change logwatch cron's hour

Tags: logwatch

I installed Logwatch with this command: yum install logwatch

Always send me logs at 3:00 server hour (I not configured this hour), how can I change cron's hour?.

Because at this moment my server is doing backups and I want to get logs after finalize.

Problem/question: where can I change the logwatch's cron?.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That depends a bit on how the logwatch package deploys the cron schedule.
I’m currently on mobile and can’t check but typical is one of two methods:

- If logwatch deploys a file in `/etc/cron.daily` then you need to remove that file and create a replacement cron batch that runs at the time of day you want. (Changing the time of all daily batches is usually not a good solution)
- When logwatch deploys a file in `/etc/cron.d` then you can edit the schedule as  that is set in the cron batch file.

Comment: I edited both files but are empty, I not find any cron for can modify hour. I have CloudLinux + WHM/cPanel, when I use command "yum install logwatch" automatically the program set cron but I don't know where modify the hour. Thank you very much!